# Telerik controls not showing in Xamarin PCL project

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, telerik

I've started my Xamarin project using telerik controls, for some reason when I deploy the app on android simulator it shows a blank screen mind you that the Xaml code I've taken from a Telerik demo example that I followed step by step and it works perfectly up until I applied those controls into my App. All References are there as per example. See below my xaml page.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:telerikPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives"
             xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PRPClockingXamarin"
             x:Class="PRPClockingXamarin.Views.MainPage"
              xmlns:telerikDataControls="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls">
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Activated="OnToolbarButtonClick" Order="Primary" Priority="0" Text="Open SideDrawer">
      <ToolbarItem.Icon>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
                        iOS="hamburgerButtonIcon.png"
                        Android="hamburgerButtonIcon.png"
                        WinPhone="Assets/hamburgerButtonIcon.png" />
      </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <Grid>
    <telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer x:Name="drawer" DrawerLength="250">
      <telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer.MainContent>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Label Text="Transition Type:"/>
          <Picker Grid.Row="1" x:Name="picker" SelectedIndexChanged="picker_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Picker.Items>
              <x:String>Push</x:String>
              <x:String>Reveal</x:String>
              <x:String>ReverseSlideOut</x:String>
              <x:String>ScaleUp</x:String>
              <x:String>SlideAlong</x:String>
              <x:String>SlideInOnTop</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
          </Picker>
          <Label Grid.Row="2" x:Name="descritpionLabel">
          </Label>
          <Button Text="Open SideDrawer" IsVisible="false" x:Name="button1"/>
        </Grid>
      </telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer.MainContent>
      <telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer.DrawerContent>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="#826182" WidthRequest="220">
          <ListView x:Name="drawerList" />
        </Grid>
      </telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer.DrawerContent>
    </telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer>
  </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on the above issue from Telerik : -

reason for such behavior would be not [registering the control's Renderer](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/sidedrawer/getting-started/sidedrawer-getting-started-register-renderer) or missing the RenderScript nuget package.